# Sampling orders for any regular vine on $n$ variables

Tags: self-study, distributions, sampling, copula

In the paper [Chatsanga and Parkes (2017)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.01174.pdf), the authors (formula (21), page 12) suggest using a sampling method based on [regular-vine copulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vine_copula) (R-vine)  which is equivalent to one scenario for random variables: 
$$\xi_1 = u_1,$$ 
$$\xi_2 = F^{-1}_{2|1}(u_2| \xi_1),$$
$$\xi_3 = F^{-1}_{3|12}(u_3| \xi_1,\xi_2 ), \tag{21}$$ 
$$...$$
$$\xi_n = F^{-1}_{n|12..n-1}(u_n| \xi_1,\xi_2, \ldots, \xi_{n-1}).$$ 
The proposed method includes the calculation of a multidimensional conditional distribution function (formula (7), page 5), and then its inverse transformation:
$$F(x_i|\textbf{v}) =\frac{\partial C_{x_i
x_j|\textbf{v}_{-j}}(F(x_i|\textbf{v}_{-j}),
F(x_j|\textbf{v}_{-j}))} {\partial F(x_j|\textbf{v}_{-j})}, \tag{7}
$$
where $C_{x_i x_j|\textbf{v}_{-j}}$ is a bivariate copula distribution function to $F_{x_i x_j|\textbf{v}_{-j}}$.

I need to generate an one scenario. Is it correct to use `rMvdc()` function here instead of using Eqs.(7), (21) mentioned above? Like below:

```
library(copula)
...
VineTree <- RVineStructureSelect(data=Mydata, type=Mytype)

Copula <- vineCopula(VineTree)
Mvdc <- mvdc(copula=Copula, MyMargins, paramMargins=Myparams)
Scenario <- rMvdc(2, Mvdc) # don't work with `1`, but should work with `2` scenarios.
```

**Update.**

In the paper ([Cooke et al, 2015](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X15000366)), authors described an algorithm for sampling a regular vine starting at an arbitrary element. The proposed algorithm named the edging up algorithm, and it implied $2^n-1$ sampling orders.